# Using __super on Clang C++

Tags: c++, clang, super

How to use `__super` on Clang C++?

Here I see that `__super` was added to Clang
http://releases.llvm.org/3.6.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html

However when trying to use it on Android NDK (which uses Clang), I get compilation errors.

Comment: What version of Clang does your NDK uses? Why don't you compile a *fresh* Clang cross-compiler from its source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This extension is specific to Windows. It won't work on Android or anywhere else by default, since it was added so that Clang can parse the Microsoft library headers. On other platforms, you need add:

```
-fms-extensions
```

to your compilation flags to enable it.